# Effective Path Finding Mob Farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was making a path finding mob farm, but I'm confused which design is more effective to use (see picture):

[image]

I felt like mobs frequently spawn on the second design, but I'm afraid they aren't going to walk into the water stream, instead they are going to walk to the place far from the water stream (The missing part from the first design), but still I don't know if this is correct or not. So any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are of similar efficiency, so there should not be any noticeable difference between the two designs. Other factors will play a much larger role, for example farm location, player position, and spawning spaces.

If I had to take a guess, I would guess that design 2 is slightly less efficient. This is because mobs in the corner will be unlikely to pathfind to another quadrant with just 1 attempt, as they are out of range. This means they will require at least 2 pathfinding attempts before crossing the water instead of 1.

You can induce mobs to pathfind more frequently by providing more solid blocks around them. Mobs pathfind to nearby solid blocks, so if there are more nearby, they will be more likely to pathfind. You can even exploit this by only placing solid blocks in areas you want mobs to walk towards, and making other places out of non-solid blocks (glass, slabs, stairs).

Comment: So I should make the first design instead of the second one?

Comment: I would build the first design, but it doesn't really matter.